# Tridion undo-checkout / check-in

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Is it possible to grant undo-checkout / check-in functionality to a user who isn't a system administrator?  I wish to grant this function to selected super users so they can remove old locks on components/pages.  I do not want to increase their privileges to system admin as this obviously prevents restricting other functions e.g. modifying schemas.

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's no possible. Consider using workflow for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a [CME GUI extension](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_DC9C231E60874E3386BBAF129328D9AD) which allows selected super users to undo check-out/check in, but that would take a bit of development.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom page to Undo Check-Out/Check-In by impersonating with admin user and share with specific users to use this page.

Note: On the history, it won't say that admin has done Undo Check-Out/Check-In.